# [JqueryMobile]Use jm,my tags are disabled after page load

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using JM to develop an app.
After completing a static page, i reference JM:

```
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The amazing thing is that some of my tags such as button,select... are disabled.
After removing JM, tags works well.

I debug the code with firefox and find that all my select tag being added disable attibute.
Example:

```
<div class="ui-select">
<div data-theme="[object Object]" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-[object Object] ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-[object ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-disabled" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">---Select Area---</span>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-[object Object] ui-icon-shadow"></span>
</span>
<select class="validate[required] mobile-selectmenu-disabled ui-state-disabled" id="plannerArea" disabled="disabled" aria-disabled="true">
        <option value="">---Select Area---</option>
        <option value="3">tetaa</option>
<option value="1">testArea666</option></select>
</div></div>
```

How could this happen?

Comment: Have you tried using a newer release of JQM, like 1.2.0? Moved your code to a jsFiddle and made some changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/QZCdD/

Comment: thanks twisy, i have updated the version of JQM. the newer release seems to be a perfact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the latest version of JQuery Mobile versus version 1.0.1.